# Simplifying a Boolean Expression 2

Tags: boolean-algebra

The boolean expression is as follows: (¬A^¬B^¬C)∨(A^¬B^C)∨(A^B^¬C)∨(A^B^C)

I have found that A⊕(¬B^¬C) is equal to the above but I have absolutely no idea on how to get this result, I have spent hours simplifying the above expression and time and time again have drawn blanks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Yes, but I have to show the steps taken to find the finished result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative.

$$
\begin{align}
A \leftrightarrow (B \lor C) &\equiv [\lnot A \land \lnot(B \lor C)] \lor [A \land(B \lor C)] \\
&\equiv    ( \lnot A \land \lnot B \land \lnot C) \lor ( A \land [(\lnot B \land C) \lor (B \land\lnot  C) \lor (B \land C)]) \\
&\equiv ( \lnot A \land \lnot B \land \lnot C) \lor (A \land \lnot B \land C) \lor (A \land B \land \lnot C) \lor (A \land B \land C)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have no experience in using '↔' but I will look into it.

Comment: Threw me off, I have used ENOR before, thank you so much for the help.